# Do Primm's defensive spells get more powerful as they level up?

Tags: secret-of-mana

Do the defensive stats-altering spells which the girl (Primm) casts upon Randi and Popoi get more powerful as they increase in level, or do they just last longer? I *know* the spells last longer, what I am looking to know is **do they have a greater effect number-wise?**

Specifically I mean spells like:

- **Defender** Raises defense
- **Speed Up** Raises Evade percentage
- **Moon Energy** Raises Critical Hit percentage

So, for example, does L8 Defender raise defense by more than L1 Defender? Or does the effect just last longer?

Answer (score 1):

Not according to [this](http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/snes/som/magicgirl.shtml):

It states that the only effect of leveling up those three spells is a longer duration for them.